# Get Forms (Jquery vs Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery

What would the equivalent of

```
document.forms[0].submit();
```

...be in jquery format? I know it would look like something similar to:

```
$("form").submit()
```

But i'm not sure how to just send a general form without knowing it's `id`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your javascript code is trying to submit first form in the page, in jQuery you've multiple ways to achieve it, one way is to use **[.first()](http://api.jquery.com/first/)**:

> Reduce the set of matched elements to the first in the set.

```
$("form").first().submit()
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm using this in a get request. I dumbed down the function for this purpose. Could you tell me if this would work?  `$.get(link,function (data){ $(data).("form").first().submit(); } );`

Comment: Try to use: `$(data).find("form").first().submit();`

Answer (score 1):

```
$("form").eq(0).submit()
```

Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the [.eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)
 method constructs a new jQuery object from one element within that
 set. The supplied index identifies the position of this element in the
 set.

Answer (score 0):

The first submits the first form on the page.

The jQuery equivalent would be:

```
$("form:eq(0)").submit();
```

But if it works in plain JavaScript, you shouldn't change it to jQuery! If it isn't broken, don't "fix" it!